# How to write a find query with condition in php-mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm having problem with find query in php-monogodb. `find()` without conditions works fine but when using condition inside `find()` method it won't give any results. How to solve this issue?

```
$connection = new Mongo();
$db = $connection->selectDB('db1');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('customers');

$cursor = $collection->find(array('CUSTOMER_ID' => $id));

$num_docs = $cursor->count();

if($num_docs > 0)
{
    foreach($cursor as $obj)
    {
        echo 'Customer-Id: '.$obj['CUSTOMER_ID']."\n";
        echo 'Customer Name: '.$obj['CUST_FIRST_NAME']." ".$obj['CUST_LAST_NAME']."\n";
        echo 'Customer Email: '.$obj['CUST_EMAIL']."\n";
        echo "\n\n\n";
    }
}
```

After var_dump($cursor->explain()); it prints:

```
array (size=3)
  'queryPlanner' => 
    array (size=6)
      'plannerVersion' => int 1
      'namespace' => string 'db1.customers' (length=13)
      'indexFilterSet' => boolean false
      'parsedQuery' => 
        array (size=1)
          'CUSTOMER_ID' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      'winningPlan' => 
        array (size=3)
          'stage' => string 'COLLSCAN' (length=8)
          'filter' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'direction' => string 'forward' (length=7)
      'rejectedPlans' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  'executionStats' => 
    array (size=7)
      'executionSuccess' => boolean true
      'nReturned' => int 0
      'executionTimeMillis' => int 1
      'totalKeysExamined' => int 0
      'totalDocsExamined' => int 325
      'executionStages' => 
        array (size=14)
          'stage' => string 'COLLSCAN' (length=8)
          'filter' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'nReturned' => int 0
          'executionTimeMillisEstimate' => int 0
          'works' => int 327
          'advanced' => int 0
          'needTime' => int 326
          'needYield' => int 0
          'saveState' => int 2
          'restoreState' => int 2
          'isEOF' => int 1
          'invalidates' => int 0
          'direction' => string 'forward' (length=7)
          'docsExamined' => int 325
      'allPlansExecution' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  'serverInfo' => 
    array (size=4)
      'host' => string 'deadpool' (length=8)
      'port' => int 27017
      'version' => string '3.2.4' (length=5)
      'gitVersion' => string 'e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30' (length=40)
```

Can you explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Try printing your query like var_dump($cursor->explain()); to see if query is correct.

Comment: I did that and I copied down the result of it below my question itself. Can you tell me what is wrong with it, I'm new to it.

Answer (score 1):

`$cursor = $collection->find(array('CUSTOMER_ID' => $id));` where are you getting the id value from.

and try not using id as sometimes it has issues finding the value esp if `$id` is used elsewhere.